# Волновой алгоритм преследования в лабиринте, кратчайший путь

Tags: c++, разработка-игр

Пишу Pacman'a, за алгоритм преследования взял волновой алгоритм, но как не крути, он тяжелый. При обновлении координат пекмена, обновляется путь призрака к нему, и тут поиск кратчайшего пути дает о себе знать. Какие есть более эффективные алгоритмы на матрицах?

вот код для поиска пути :

```
   void Enemy::getPathToTarget() {
    pathToPacman.clear ();
    const Position * playerPosition = Player::playerPosition ();
    Field = Maze::getField ();
    int height = Field.size();
    int width  = Field[0].size();
    int dx[4] = {1, 0, -1, 0};
    int dy[4] = {0, 1, 0, -1};
    int d, x, y, k;
    bool stop;
    Field[playerPosition->x][playerPosition->y] = 1;
    if (Field[position->x][position->y] == 0 ||
         Field[playerPosition->x][playerPosition->y] == 0)
              return;

    d = 6;
    Field[position->x][position->y]  = 6;
    do {
         stop = true;
       for ( y = 0; y < height; ++y )
         for ( x = 0; x < width;++x )
        if ( Field[y][x] == d ) {
            for ( k = 0; k < 4; ++k ) {
                int iy=y + dy[k];
                int ix = x + dx[k];
                if ( iy >= 0 && iy < height && ix >= 0 && ix < width &&
                     ((Field[iy][ix] == 1) || (Field[iy][ix] == 2) ||
                     (Field[iy][ix] == 3))) {
                     stop = false;
                     Field[iy][ix] = d + 1;
                }
            }
        }
      ++d;
    } while ( !stop && (Field[playerPosition->x][playerPosition->y] == 1 ||
      (Field[playerPosition->x][playerPosition->y] == 2) ||
        Field[playerPosition->x][playerPosition->y] == 3));
    if (Field[playerPosition->x][playerPosition->y] == 1)
    return;

    d = Field[playerPosition->x][playerPosition->
    y = playerPosition->x;
    x = playerPosition->y;
    int val = 0;
    while ( d > 6 ) {
       pathToPacman.push (Position(y, x));
       d--;
       for (k = 0; k < 4; ++k) {
           int iy=y + dy[k], ix = x + dx[k];
           if ( iy >= 0 && iy < height && ix >= 0 && ix < width &&
           Field[iy][ix] == d)  {
           x  = x + dx[k];
           y = y + dy[k];
          break;
      }
    }
  }
 timer.start (10000);
}
```

Comment: Нужно очень криво написать поиск кратчайшего пути на решётке (на матрице), чтобы он давал о себе знать. При одинаковой длине рёбер его сложность равна `O(n)`, где `n` - число вершин графа-решётки.

Comment: Выходит так, что он очень долго разбрасывает волны, пока не дойдет до заданной кординаты...

Comment: @Max даже при размере таблицы 1000*1000 реально делать 100 обсчётов в секунду на слабом железе.

Comment: @pavel  Торвальдс говорил: "Болтовня ничего не стоит, покажите нам код.".Код вот. Если вы говорите, что все должно быть так глядко, то будьте добры, указать где я ошибся.

Comment: @Max я могу привести алгоритм который работает с такой скоростью. Если вы написали медленнее значит это ошибка именно вашего алгоритма. И самое главное место - `do {
       for ( y = 0; y < height; ++y )
         for ( x = 0; x < width;++x )` Ничего что это уже потенциальная сложность вместо `O(N*M)` `O(N*N*M*M)` дальше не читал. Это не волновой обход и ничего общего с ним не имеет. Я минуты 2 пытался найти в этом коде `очередь` или что-то (массив, список, вектор) на неё похожий, не сумел.

Comment: @pavel очередь для чего?

Comment: @Max http://e-maxx.ru/algo/bfs вот алгоритм. Грубо идея - кладём в очередь вершину в которой мы сейчас и идём именно из неё, а не перебираем весь массив, пытаясь найти её.

Comment: @pavel какое отношение имеет поиск в ширину к волновому алгоритму?

Comment: @Max простите, а волновой алгоритм это что?) Я уточню, это абсолютно один и тот же алгоритм, просто одно название общепринято (`BFS` особенно) а 2 не особо. Даже вики с этим согласна `Алгори́тм волново́й трассиро́вки (волновой алгоритм, алгоритм Ли) — алгоритм поиска пути, алгоритм поиска кратчайшего пути на планарном графе. Принадлежит к алгоритмам, основанным на методах поиска в ширину.`

Comment: @pavel ключевое слово "основанных" это раз, а второе то, что в волновом алгортме не используется  для хранения посещенных вершин.

Answer (score 3):

У вас имеются следующие условия:

1. Лабиринт с коридорами шириной в 1 клетку
2. 1 - 3 направления движения, поскольку призрак не может развернуться на предыдущую клетку.
3. Положение Пакмана
4. Положение Призрака

Отсюда простейший алгоритм последовательного перебора клеток с выборкой минимальной дистанции.

Если Вы хотите реализовать классический алгоритм преследования, то учтите, что у каждого призрака своя модель поведения и только Красный призрак ориентируется точно на позицию Пакмана. 
Если английский не проблема, настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться с PacMan Dossier, где подробно расписаны тонкости игры.
http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3938/the_pacman_dossier.php?print=1

Вот вам мой пример реализации на C# под юньку, но думаю разобраться будет не сложно. Естественно код можно упростить одним циклом на 4 направления, но здесь оставил подробно для наглядности:

**Update:** Забыл упомянуть, что искать весь путь до Пакмана не нужно, необходимо искать лишь наиболее предпочтительную клетку для следующего шага. Этот код как раз для выборки следующего шага.

```
protected void GetMinNextPosition()
{
    int ix = Mathf.FloorToInt(_myTrans.position.x);
    int iy = Mathf.FloorToInt(_myTrans.position.y);

    float dist = float.MaxValue;
    Direction _potencialDir = Direction.None;

    if (!GameManager.Instance.Map[ix - 1, iy].IsObstacle && _oppositeDirection != Direction.Left)
    {
        float newDist = Vector3.Distance(new Vector3(ix - 1, iy), _target);
        if (newDist < dist)
        {
            dist = newDist;
            _potencialDir = Direction.Left;
        }
    }
    if (!GameManager.Instance.Map[ix + 1, iy].IsObstacle && _oppositeDirection != Direction.Right)
    {
        float newDist = Vector3.Distance(new Vector3(ix + 1, iy), _target);
        if (newDist < dist)
        {
            dist = newDist;
            _potencialDir = Direction.Right;
        }
    }
    if (!GameManager.Instance.Map[ix, iy - 1].IsObstacle && _oppositeDirection != Direction.Down)
    {
        float newDist = Vector3.Distance(new Vector3(ix, iy - 1), _target);
        if (newDist < dist)
        {
            dist = newDist;
            _potencialDir = Direction.Down;
        }
    }
    if (!GameManager.Instance.Map[ix, iy + 1].IsObstacle && _oppositeDirection != Direction.Up)
    {
        float newDist = Vector3.Distance(new Vector3(ix, iy + 1), _target);
        if (newDist < dist)
        {
            dist = newDist;
            _potencialDir = Direction.Up;
        }
    }
    SetDirection(_potencialDir, ix, iy);
}
```